# Using JFileChooser to reselect files in directory

Tags: java, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I am trying to create a UI in Java so that users can browse through images in a directory just by the use of JButtons. However, whenever I select a new image using JFileChooser, the images appends to each other. How can I delete the previous image and show that new one?

I am also trying to figure out how to go on to the next/previous image in the directory just by clicking on the next/previous button. How do I achieve that? Below is my code for my ButtonListener:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == chooseBtn)
        {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

            if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
            {
                File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                String fileName = selectedFile.toString();
                image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(fileName));
                imgPanel.add(image);
                frame.add(imgPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
                frame.repaint();
                frame.validate();
            }
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == nextBtn)
        {
            System.out.println("Next");
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == prevBtn)
        {
            System.out.println("Previous");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you create new lables ..change imageicon instead

Comment: what is the question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the problem.you create new labels and add to panel  .that's why images append to panel

```
  if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                String fileName = selectedFile.toString();
                image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(fileName));
                imgPanel.add(image);
                frame.add(imgPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
                frame.repaint();
                frame.validate();
     }
```

don't create lables each time.just onetime and change image icon when  choose image

```
////don't repeate this code block
image = new JLabel();
imgPanel.add(image);
frame.add(imgPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
frame.repaint();
frame.validate();
/////////

  if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                String fileName = selectedFile.toString();
                image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(fileName )); 
                //repaint
                frame.repaint();

   }
```